# Post a message to Kafka topic using postman

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, postman

I have created a topic into Kafka, And I am trying to post a message using postman but I am getting internal server error

Content-type:application/json
Body:

```
{
 "records": [
{
  "key": "somekey",
  "value": {"foo": "bar"}
},
{
  "value": [ "foo", "bar" ],
  "partition": 1
},
{
  "value": 53.5
}
]
}
```

Response:

```
{
"error_code": 500,
"message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

Any guess what is the issue ?

Comment: Which URL you are using to post this msg to Kafka? It should undergo through KafkaProducer using appropriate serialization to be posted.

Comment: I have used "kafka_rest_url" mentioned in Service credentials section, and in the header i have added "X-Auth-Token" with "api_key" in the header.

Comment: The get topics is working fine using postman but Post not working

Comment: Is it your local cluster or remote? Admin might have blocked POST requests (as in our shop).

Comment: Any errors/warnings in Kafka Rest logs? Also, body and response is not enough so please share URL, headers etc.

Comment: It would help if you could get the server logs

Comment: How can I get the logs, it is remote deployed on cloud message hub, and I am new at this area and I couldn't,t find any logs at the server side :(